# Code is Crashing when items are not found

Tags: vba

I am trying to write a code to look for a piece of a word then based off them do the formatting below. The problem is the words are not always in the data.

Ideal I would like to just search for "Implementation Record Type:" then loop through cells A1:Q1000 and do the same formatting to all cells with that word.

```
  Columns("A:A").Select
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Find(What:="Implementation Record Type: ^Parent Record", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
        ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 23

Columns("A:A").Select
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Find(What:="Implementation Record Type: Child Record", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 17).Interior.ColorIndex = 23
        ActiveCell.Font.ColorIndex = 2
        ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 23

Columns("A:A").Select
On Error Resume Next
Cells.Find(What:="Grand Totals", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 17).Interior.Color = 5296274
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = 5296274
```

Comment: On what line does it crash?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is shoving all errors under the carpet - bascically this code *cannot* possibly be *crashing*.

Comment: On the second Cells.Find I get the runtime error 91

Comment: @Tony what is a "runtime error 91" when you look for it?

Comment: @retailcoder - it *can* crash if the OP has "break on all errors" set in their VBE options...

Answer (score 0):

Set a range variable and search for the string

Test the range if it found something

If the range is found, format with your format conditions

```
Dim strSearch As String
Dim rngTemp As Range

strSearch = "Implementation Record Type: ^Parent Record"

On Error Resume Next
Set rngTemp = Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlPart)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
    'Your format command goes here
End If

strSearch = "Implementation Record Type: Child Record"

On Error Resume Next
Set rngTemp = Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlPart)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
    'Your format command goes here
End If

strSearch = "Grand Totals"

On Error Resume Next
Set rngTemp = Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlPart)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rngTemp Is Nothing Then
    'Your format command goes here
End If
```